# Can a penetration test write-up be used as a bachelor thesis?

Tags: thesis, bachelor

I'm doing a Computer Science degree in university. While the program provided by the uni is not focused, I'm personally focusing on studying security, aiming to become a Penetration Tester/Red Teamer. I'd like to do a penetration test (on a real system with permission or a simulated system) and make the write-up my thesis.

I've emailed the main professor in Computer Security of my university but haven't yet received a reply. I'd like answers besides "just ask your professor" and "wait for a reply".

I'd like opinions from other university professors: Can a pentest write-up be used as a bachelor thesis?

Comment: This topic can be used for BSc thesis in some universities and won't be allowed in others. The answer depends on the rules and customs of your Department and University.  Just ask your professor.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but the only valid answer will come from the professor. It is acceptable or not based on their views only.

But be aware that a penetration test on a real system can come with legal implications. Claiming to be a white hat may hold little weight with authorities. Gaining permission, as you suggest, might be very difficult as institutions running real system have a lot of concerns beyond the obvious. Their own legal department might nix any such project.

A simulated system is fine, though seldom has sufficient protections in place for a valid test. An iterative, competitive, duel between two teams (Red team, Blue team) might be interesting.

The answer to the general question, though, is yes, such a test can be used as a thesis, but only with the consent of the advisor. The general answer to the question has exactly zero impact on your case.

Comment: It's OK if it doesn't apply to my particular case. I just wanted some opinions. I'd love to do a Red vs Blue but I'm not sure I can find a blue team for that in my course...